# How to correctly inflate a Gridview with a ConstraintLayout and maintain aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-inflate

I have a two column gridview that is dynamically populated with rows of users, so each cell refers to a user. I am currently inflating a Framelayout that I use as the view for each cell but I am struggling with the inflation of this layout.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(mContext);
    int width = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_friend_profile, parent, false);
    TextView username = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.add_friend_txt_name);
    username.setText(friends.get(position));

    layout.addView(view);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams( (width / 2) , (width / 2)));

    return layout;
}
```

The layout consists of ImageView as the background (A portrait border), a TextView for the users name, an ImageView for a profile picture and a Button to add the user.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_profile_bg"
        android:id="@+id/add_friend_profile_border"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/add_friend_txt_name"
        android:text="@string/ffsu_screen_user"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/add_friend_profile_border"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/add_friend_profile_border"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/add_friend_profile_border"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.13" />

    <ImageView
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_account_box_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/add_friend_img_pic"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/add_friend_profile_border"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/add_friend_profile_border"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add_friend_txt_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/add_friend_profile_border"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/add_friend_profile_add"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/add_friend_btn_add"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add_friend_img_pic"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/add_friend_profile_border"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/add_friend_profile_border"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_active"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The main problem I am having is the font size of the textview and the width and height of the ImageView and button is a good size on the layout, it will be too large when inflated in the cell of the GridView.

[Screenshot of Android GUI design for layout being inflated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8aKA.png)

[Screenshot of result of inflating layout in GridView cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1vCM.jpg)

Comment: Please include relevant source code in your question.

Comment: @ErnestZamelczyk I have included relevant source code now, I hope it provides more clarity to my problem. I initially avoided the inclusions because I did not want to bloat the post (New to posting!) :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your views don't fit inside the grid cells. But if we create a chain in the constraint layout, then the views will adjust themselves.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/add_friend_profile_border"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_profile_bg"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add_friend_txt_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ffsu_screen_user"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/add_friend_profile_border"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/add_friend_profile_border"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/add_friend_img_pic"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/add_friend_img_pic"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add_friend_txt_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/add_friend_btn_add"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_account_box_black_24dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_friend_btn_add"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add_friend_profile_add"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_active"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add_friend_img_pic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Though I strongly suggest you to remove the first ImageView and just set background on the constraint layout. Margins between items should be managed by `horizontalSpacing` and `verticalSpacing` in GridView. Also I'd suggest making all those margins smaller. That's just a poor use of space.

Comment: What does creating a chain do to improve the sizing of the views in the grid cell? I have tried to implement an image as a background but because I am using a vector image and targeting a lower SDK I am having problems. The spacing is a good tipe but I require padding on the sides closest to the screen edges and from playing around with the spacing you recommended it does not achieve this. Thanks for trying to help though, really appreciate it!